# How to modify the environment variables and working directory of gdbserver --multi without restarting it?

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

When I run a program that prints the environment from `environ` locally with:

```
./gdb myprintenv
```

I can change environment variables across runs with:

```
run
set environment asdf=qwer
run
```

Is there any way to do that with `gdbserver --multi`?

I'm running it as:

```
gdbserver --multi :1234 ./myprintenv
```

and then locally:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb -ex 'target extended-remote remotehost:1234' ./myprintenv
```

then the command:

```
set environment asdf=qwer
run
```

has no effect.

I can change the variables with:

```
asdf=qwer gdbserver --multi :1234 ./myprintenv
```

but that is annoying as it requires the `mon exit`, go to board, rerun, go to host, reconnect dance.

The same goes for working directory, which you can [change with `cd` locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303350/how-do-you-set-the-current-directory-of-a-debugged-process), but not on the server apparently.

One alternative would be to launch `gdbserver` with SSH every time without `--multi`, just like Eclipse does, but that has the downside that it is harder to see stdout: [How can I reach STDIN/STDOUT through a gdbserver session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082005/how-can-i-reach-stdin-stdout-through-a-gdbserver-session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature doesn't exist in gdb yet.  It's being developed though: https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2017-08/msg00000.html